# MovieClip extension

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, movieclip

I have been trying to develop a CustomButton class that extends MovieClip, however I am having problems. I have got this error:

> ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on
>   mkh.custombutton::CustomButton(). Expected 2, got 0.  at
>   flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()     at flash.display::Sprite()
>     at flash.display::MovieClip()

I've tried to debug my code, but it says

> "Cannot display source code at this location."

I am not sure where is the problem, but I suppose it's in the constructor:

```
public function CustomButton( buttonlabel:String, animationAR:Array,     active:Boolean=true, animated:Boolean = false, type:String = "free", group:int = 0 )
```

I would be very grateful if anyone helped me. Thank you.

EDIT2: I think I know why it's not appearing, so nevermind.

Comment: I need to see more than just the constructor... Try pasting how you initialize the class, and where you are calling the constructor as well and I will take a look and see if anything jumps out at me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because you're not showing all the code that is required to accurately tell what the issue is. The symptom of this is the fact that there are 3 answers on a question about constructor arguments. That's ridiculous. Please post the code that initiates this error. If you don't know how to determine that even when the debugger says the source cannot be displayed, this tells me you haven't spent more than 10 seconds debugging. Start commenting out code until the app compiles file. Once it does, you've found the offending line(s). Post them please.

Comment: I'll also remove my downvote once you edit this question and turn it into a real, specific question instead of a mini game on Jeopardy.

Comment: @MKII Have you seen danii's answer? His makes the most sense out of them all here. Did you set a library object to have a base class of CustomButton?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am very new to AS3 and Flash (I started a few weeks ago) and there is a lot I still have to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is, now I hope I can explain to you clearly enough (English is not my first language). Did you by any chance make a graphic MovieClip in the Flash program and linked it to your CustomButton class? If so, be careful with the instances you might have on the stage, because when Flash creates the Sprites/Movieclips objects that are on the stage it calls their constructor **without any parameters**.

To avoid this, either:

- Set default values for **all** parameters in your CustomButtonClass (EDIT: which would solve your problem, but is not very good practice)
- Use **addChild** to put instances of your Button onto the stage (I recommend this one)

Hope this helps!

Comment: -1 for guessing and for promoting very bad object composition. The whole point of having constructor arguments is for object composition and setting a bunch of defaults is just ridiculous. If you don't need to abstract away anything special in the constructor you should eliminate the constructor arguments all together and use encapsulated members and accessors to customize your object post-creation.

Comment: The thing is, when I was starting in Flash I ran into this problem several times, so I am sure I am giving him the right way to solve the problem If you actually READ my answer before downvoting, you would see I didn't "promote" anything, in fact my recommendation was NOT setting default values, instead to use ADDCHILD (which for the problem he's getting, I am sure he's not using). If you don't understand neither the question nor my answer, I wonder why are you downvoting anything?

Comment: I removed the downvote because I skipped over the part about adding objects to the stage and the constructor being called without params. That actually makes perfect sense. I do still however completely disagree with poor object composition by having a bunch of constructor arguments, and default ones at that.

Comment: You might dislike me and my "attitude" (I'm just defending my answer, which I'm sure everyone here does) but my answer is helpful and I believe it doesn't deserve the -1.

Comment: Indeed danii's reply was helpful, however if I use addChild it won't draw the button...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you must be instantiating CustomButton without passing it any arguments.

Like so:

```
var cBtn = new CustomButton();
```

However, you constructor has 2 arguments that must be passed - buttonLabel and animationAR (the rest are OK because they are assigned a default value).

So you should be doing something like this:

```
var cBtn = new CustomButton('Test', someArray);
```

Comment: to expand on this answer, note that you *can send in more params, the first two are just the required ones.

Comment: Actually I used two arguments: public var mcButton:CustomButton = new CustomButton( 'Hello', arAR, true );

Comment: @MKII: If that's the case, there's not enough information to solve this. You need to post some more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function CustomButton(
        buttonlabel:String,
        animationAR:Array,
        active:Boolean=true,
        animated:Boolean = false,
        type:String = "free",
        group:int = 0
    );
```

That's how you defined your constructor. This means that the first 2 arguments (`buttonlabel` abd `animationAR`) are required arguments. The rest are optional.

Now if you try to instantiate this like

```
var cb:CustomButton=new CustomButton();
```

You are not passing any arguments to the constructot, which will throw that error.
Note that this is what happens when you create the object directly in the UI.

A way to fix this would be to redefine the constructor as:

```
public function CustomButton(
        buttonlabel:String="CustomButton",
        animationAR:Array=[],
        active:Boolean=true,
        animated:Boolean = false,
        type:String = "free",
        group:int = 0
    );
```

This makes all arguments optional and should work. Of course, you'll be best off putting the default value of the arguments as something you know will work. For example, in my example, the empty array default for `animationAR` could break your code, in which case you need to add this to the constructor body:

```
if(animationAR.length==0) {
    animationAR.push(new Animation());
    //YOU WILL HAVE TO CHANGE THIS LINE TO CORRESPOND TO YOUR CODE
}
```

OR ELSE, you could instantiate the object as

```
var cb:CustomButton=new CustomButton("My Crazy-ass CustomButton", animArray);
```

Comment: Actually I used two arguments: public var mcButton:CustomButton = new CustomButton( 'Hello', arAR, true );

Comment: This is why you need to learn to properly debug and post the real offending line here, @MKII. Your constructor is obviously not the source of the issue, unless you've compiled your class into a runtime shared library and are instantiating it from there. We can tell this by seeing that the IDE states it cannot show the source code of the offending line. If this error originated from your class constructor and the class as well as the line instantiating it are in plain text and being compiled, the compiler would be able to show the source of the error.